# Count number of rows in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to count number of rows in this subquery:

```
select t.*
FROM(
select 1 as first, 2 as second
union
select 1 as first, 3 as second
) t
```

so expected result is:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| first | second | count |
+-------+--------+-------+
|     1 |      2 |     2 |
|     1 |      3 |     2 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

What I've already tried is to include `count(*)` into query, but it doesn't work. Any idea on this problem?

Comment: if there is one more row then with values 2 as first, 5 as second then what would be the result. Is it three or two ?

Comment: It is three in case of three rows.

Comment: You can read more about window function. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the window function.

The window functions can be invaluable, and well worth your time to get comfortable with them.

**Example**

```
select t.*
      ,count = sum(1) over ()
FROM(
select 1 as first, 2 as second
union
select 1 as first, 3 as second
) t
```

**Returns**

```
first   second  count
1       2       2
1       3       2
```

Comment: why did you use `sum(1)` instead of `count`?

Comment: @Magnus Just a choice.  As you well know, either would work, In this case, there is no risk of sum() returning a null.  Besides, I'm a lazy man, and I saved two keystrokes  ... until now :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - thanks a lot for answer. The only thing I don't understand is this: sum(1) - what is 1 meaning here? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @FrenkyB  sum(1) is essentially the same as count(*).  We're just counting or summing the number of records.   Just for fun, see what happens if you sum(10)... in this example, the count would be 20 (no value other than an illustration)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a CTE.

```
with cte as
(
    select 1 as first, 2 as second
    union
    select 1 as first, 3 as second
)
select 
    cte.*,
    (select count(*) from cte) as [count]
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
select t.*, count(*) over (order by first  ) count
FROM(
select 1 as first, 1 as second
union
select 1 as first, 2 as second
union
select 1 as first, 3 as second
union
select 2 as first, 4 as second
) t
```

or

```
select distinct t.first, count(*) over (order by first  ) count
FROM(
select 1 as first, 1 as second
union
select 1 as first, 2 as second
union
select 1 as first, 3 as second
union
select 2 as first, 4 as second
) t
```